# Paint path in Ida according to gdb log file

Tags: ida, idapython, gdb

In Gdb I put script that print each instruction to gdb.txt file.

I want to load this file to Ida to show and print/paint the path that the process has been running.

The gdb script is

```
# not strictly required, but you'll likely want the log anyway 
(gdb) set logging on

# ask gdb to not stop every screen-full 
(gdb) set height 0

(gdb) while 1
 > x/i $pc
 > stepi
 > end
```

Is there any python /module in Ida that already do that?

If no, how can I do that nicely?

Answer (score 1):

[Lighthouse](https://github.com/gaasedelen/lighthouse) might be the one of the best solutions for this.

Instead of using `gdb` to trace your execution you can use something like [Dynamorio](https://dynamorio.org/page_drcov.html) or a pintool that is compatible with IDA [Lighthouse](https://github.com/gaasedelen/lighthouse)

You can also modify your script to produce compatible output. You can use existing pintools and frida script present [here](https://github.com/gaasedelen/lighthouse/tree/develop/coverage)